# How many committees of five contain at least one African and one European?

Tags: combinatorics

A council consists of three Europeans, four Americans, three Asians, and five Africans.

How many committees of five contain at least one African and one European?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer

A full enumeration would lead to :

5 - Africans (A), 3 Europeans(E) and 7 Others (O)

For the said problem:

These are the choices

1A,1E,3O - 5C1*3C1*7C3 - 525

2A,1E,2O - 5C2*3C1*7C2 - 630

3A,1E,1O - 5C3*3C1*7C1 - 210

4A,1E - 5C4*3C1 - 15

1A,2E,2O - 5C1*3C2*7C2  - 315

1A,3E,1O - 5C1*3C3*7C1 - 35

2A,2E - 5C2*3C3*7C1 - 210

3A,2E - 5C3* 3C2 - 30

2A,3E - 5C2*3C3 - 10

Totals = 1980

Others

0A,1E,4O - 3C1*7C4 = 105

0A,2E,3O = 3C2*7C3 - 105

0A,3C,2O = 3C3*7C2 - 21

1A,0E,4O = 5C1*7C4 = 175

2A,0E,3O = 5C2*7C3 = 350

3A,0E,2O - 5C3*7C2 = 210

4A,0E,1O - 5C4*7C1 = 35

5A - 5C5 - 1

5O - 7C5 - 21

Total of Remainder - 1023

Total = 1023+1980 = 3003 = 15C5

I think the answer is 1980 ******

Thanks

Satish

Comment: One liner would be: [ 15C5 - 5C0(3C1*7C4+3C2*7C3+3C3*7C2) - 3C0*(5C1*7C4+5C2*7C3+5C3*7C2+5C4*7C1+5C5) - 7C5].  It is not as simple as it appears.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It isn't that difficult to calculate the number of committees that contain no Europeans, the number of committees that contain no Africans, and the number of committees that contain neither.

Then, you can use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle to get the number of committees that contain either no Africans or no Europeans (or possibly both), and subtract from the total number of committees.

Comment: Would the answer be: (15 choose 5) - [(7 choose 5) + (9 choose 4) + (11 choose 4)] = 2526?

Comment: That's the solution that I think is correct or what do you suggest @Dennis ?

Comment: The "total number" and the "number with none of either" look right, but the other two combinations look off.

Comment: It's because I think the number of committees that contain one African and no Europeans result in 15 (total) - 3 (Europeans) - 1 (African) = 11 and since we know in advance that the committees contain 1 African that will result in 5 - 1 = 4. So "11 choose 4". I proceeded in a similar way in the other part. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's a little bit off, but I realized that my hint is also misleading. Let me fix it first.